# Checking the validity of a given date

Tags: java

```
package MyJava10;

import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Test2 {


public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    int a,b,c;
    String as,bs,cs;

    System.out.println("enter the date");

    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    String s=sc.next();


    as=s.substring(0,2);
    bs=s.substring(3,5);
    cs=s.substring(6);
    a=Integer.valueOf(as);
    b=Integer.valueOf(bs);
    c=Integer.valueOf(cs);

    Calendar cal=new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setLenient(false);
    cal.set(c, b-1, a);
    System.out.println(cs+'/'+bs+'/'+as);
}
}
```

As you can see, I am trying to know whether a given date is valid. I have coded as given and have set
`cal.setLenient(false);`.

Unfortunately, when I am giving an invalid date, no error is shown.

Help of any kind will be greatly appreciable. Thanks :)
Sorry if this question has been asked before by anyone else; if so, giving the URL shall be of great help.

Comment: What is the error that you are expecting? How do you intent to check the errors? Provide a shorter string as input and you should see something.

Comment: Check with this question..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4010258/how-to-check-validity-of-date-string

Answer (score 1):

You can have a function to check date validity like this:

```
public static String DATE_FORMAT = "MM/dd/yyyy";

public static boolean isDateValid(String date) {
    try {
        DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(DATE_FORMAT);
        df.setLenient(false);
        df.parse(date);
        return true;
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

You can change `DATE_FORMAT` according to your needing ([documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)). Then your main is:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the date:");
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String date = scanner.next();

    if (isDateValid(date))
        System.out.println("Valid date");
    else
        System.out.println("Invalid date");

    scanner.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do something like this,

```
    Calendar cal=new GregorianCalendar();
    cal.setLenient(false);
    cal.set(2014, 8, 32);
    System.out.println(cal.getTime());
```

You will get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: DAY_OF_MONTH
    at java.util.GregorianCalendar.computeTime(GregorianCalendar.java:2316)
    at java.util.Calendar.updateTime(Calendar.java:2265)
    at java.util.Calendar.getTimeInMillis(Calendar.java:1049)
    at java.util.Calendar.getTime(Calendar.java:1022)
    at Question.main(Question.java:39)
```

Comment: Well, thanks. But I still have a question. Why no error is shown when we set the date with cal.set(int,int,int) method ?

Comment: The error isn't shown until you attempt to get the value back. Probably because you could be performing Date arithmetic.