# how to check if a date pattern is valid in java?

Tags: java

Im trying to achive this: I have a method that recieves a string that is the format of a date pattern (example "dd/mm/yyyy") and the method has to validate if the pattern is valid in java or not.
Example, lets say I have the following input:

```
String input1="dd/mm/yyyy";
String input2="mm/dd/yyyy";
String input3"cceq.der.sads";
String input4= "dd-M-yyyy hh:mm:ss"

public Boolean validPatternDate(String in){
//The code im looking for
}
```

The result of each input being applied to the validPatternDate method is going to be:

```
input1 True
input2 True
input3 False
input4 True
```

Is there a way of doing this in java? Thanks

Comment: Considering *you* need to define what patterns your consider valid, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43692146/133203).

Comment: did you try to instanciate a simpledateformat or a DateTimeFormatter object with the pattern?

Comment: Thanks for answering. What is the result of instanciate a simpledateformat with a wrong pattern? an exception?

Comment: If you use [SimpleDateFormat#parse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#parse(java.lang.String,java.text.ParsePosition)), it should return `null` for errors.

Comment: Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20231539/java-check-the-date-format-of-current-string-is-according-to-required-format-or/20232680). It should answer you question.

Comment: @njzk2 and others, I recommend you never use `SimpleDateFormat`. That class is notoriously troublesome and long outdated. Instead use `DateTimeFormatter` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## tl;dr

Try `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern` while trapping for `IllegalArgumentException`.

```
try {
    formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( input ) ;
} catch ( IllegalArgumentException e ) {
    … // Handle exception thrown for invalid input formatting pattern.
}
```

Better yet, let `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…` automatically localize instead of you trying to allow troublesome arbitrary format strings.

## Localize, instead

Accepting any arbitrary formatting pattern is going to be a problematic headache. Formatting patterns are complicated and subtle.

In addition, many of the formats will require that you also specify a `Locale` to determine the human language and cultural norms necessary to decide issues such as translation of month name & day-of-week name & so on, abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, and more.

I suggest you instead let *java.time* localize. Instead of passing a formatting pattern, you would pass a [`FormatStyle`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/FormatStyle.html) enum object (or string of its name), and a [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html) object. But as I mentioned above, you need to pass a `Locale` in any event.

Use the `FormatStyle` and `Locale` to get a localizing [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) object.

```
FormatStyle style = FormatStyle.MEDIUM ;
Locale locale = Locale.CANADA_FRENCH ;

DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( style ).withLocale( locale ) ;
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now( ZoneId.of( "Africa/Tunis" ) ) ;
String output = localDate.format( formatter ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/2j9ssT).

> 12 juill. 2021

## Trap `IllegalArgumentException`

If you insist on your approach of accepting arbitrary formatting patterns, you can attempt to use that format with `DateTimeFormatter` class. Call its `ofPattern` method. Trap for the [`IllegalArgumentException`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html) thrown if the pattern is invalid.

```
String input = "dd/mm/yyyy" ;
DateTimeFormatter f = null ;
try {
    formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( input ) ;
} catch ( IllegalArgumentException e ) {
    … // Handle exception thrown for invalid input formatting pattern.
}
```

Beware: As mentioned above, some formats require a [`Locale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Locale.html). So you should be receiving a locale argument as well as a formatting pattern, and calling [`DateTimeFormatter.withLocale`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#withLocale(java.util.Locale)).

Answer (score 2):

Basil Bourque has already given the good answer. I wanted to add a modest supplement.

### All of your input patterns are incorrect

It appears to me that none of your patterns `input1` through `input4` is correct! You are using almost only lower case letters in your patterns. Format patterns are case sensitive, and I am convinced that you wanted to use some upper case letters for some of the letters. For example `dd/MM/yyyy` could be a valid pattern for day, month and year separated by slashes. Your `input1`, `dd/mm/yyyy` is not. And the code by Basil Bourque does not catch this error since lower case `m` is a valid pattern letter — for minute of hour (your are using both `M` and `mm` correctly in your `input4`).

You may attempt to catch some of such errors by parsing or formatting using the formatter that you get from `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern()`. The challenge is which string to parse, which date-time type to parse it into (which can be essential) or which date-time type to format. Without this knowledge it is not going to work.

### Catching all errors is not realistic

On the curious side `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern()` will let patterns through that in a human eye are clearly meaningless because pretty many pattern letters are valid. For example:

```
    String input = "MAD way";
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(input);
    System.out.println(formatter.format(LocalDateTime.now(ZoneId.systemDefault())));
```

Output:

> 786390607193 28PM2021

There is realistically nothing you can do about this, and it is very unlikely to be a problem in practice.

### Do not return an object

Don’t return a `Boolean` object. What would null signify here? Return a primitive `boolean` so the caller knows that the result is always either false or true.